# Крякнутый Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, android, лицензирование

Здравствуйте!

У меня такой вопрос. Как известно, под android в основном пишут на java. Есть также и другие средства, позволяющие писать на других языках - xamarin и c#, rad studio и delphi, qt и С++. Хотел бы остановиться на xamarin. Как известно, это платный продукт, который стоит 1000-1900 долларов в год.

Теперь сам вопрос: допустим, я (о горе мне) скачал крякнутый продукт Xamarin, не заплатив им их тысячу долларов и с его помощью сделал какое-нибудь приложение. После этого я хочу выложить приложение в Play Google. Что произойдет в таком случае? Будет ли мое приложение как-либо блокировано или меня ждут какие-то другие кары и лишения? 
Да, я понимаю, что пользоваться кряками нехорошо, но вопрос скорее из любопытства.

Comment: Думаю, что, скорее всего, будет так. Если Ваше приложение будет иметь 10-20 загрузок в год, то никто не будет трогать. А вот если оно станет популярно и ещё за него денежку будете брать, вот тогда, скорее всего, займутся. В начале, скорее всего, просто предложат мировую в виде покупки лицензии.

Comment: а как вообще сотрудники Xamarin или хотя бы Google смогут определить, что свое приложение я сделал с помощью именно этого продукта?

Comment: Для начала, Гугл имеет доступ к apk файлу. А этого уже предостаточно. Как минимум отличить, сделано java'оф или C# особой проблемой не будет. Но обычно все компиляторы любят добавлять имя версии себя. Это выдаст с потрохами.

Comment: я наверное неправильно выразился. Я имиею в виду как тот же гугл поймет что мой Xamarin был крякнутым? И тем более как об этом узнает Xamarin?

Comment: Позволю себе все же отметить, что Xamarin Indie на год на две платформы (iOS и Android) стоить $538.20, что не кажется огромной суммой даже при нынешнем курсе.

Comment: Вопросы о способе нарушения или обхода лицензии на ПО не входят в допустимую тематику Stack Overflow на русском.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть очень простой способ - просто спросить у Вас: "А где Ваша лицензия?" Покупая у Xamarin продукт с лицензией, Вы же оставляете им свое имя/телефон/почту.

То есть, по-простому, смотрят на продукт в маркете, видят, что он делается компанией "Рога и копыто". Смотрят в свою базу лицензий - а там нет такого. И отправят компании запрос.